# Newton's Method with 2 equations

Tags: newton-series

Let $$f(x) =
\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3-1}{\sqrt{x}-1}, & x > 1\\
\arccos(x-1)-x^2, & x \leq 1\end{cases}$$

Use Newton's method with $x_{0} =1$, compute the second iterate to approximate value $c$ where $c$ is a stationary value that lies in the x-axis for some $0<c<1$

Since the Newton's method is as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}$$

$$x_{1}=x_{0}-\frac{acos(0)-1}{-asin(0)-2}$$

Is this correct? What should I proceed on from here?

Comment: What are the values of $\arccos(0)$ and $\arcsin(0)$?

Comment: $\pi /2$ and 0 respectively

Comment: So what's the value of $x_1$?

Comment: You are applying Newton's method to the wrong function. Please note that Newton's method finds roots (places where $f(x) = 0$). But you are not looking for a root of $f$. you are looking for a *stationary value*. That is,  a place where $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: So I will only apply after I differentiate the second eq?